# HTML will break if a description list contains a div

Tags: tinymce

I would like my list not to break. Does anyone else have an idea?

My configuration from tiny

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: [
          'autolink',
          'link',
          'image',
          'lists',
          'advlist',
          'preview',
          'searchreplace',
          'visualblocks',
          'code',
          'fullscreen',
          'insertdatetime',
          'media',
          'table',
          'emoticons',
          'template',
        ],
     toolbar: "code",
     valid_children: '*[*]',
     valid_elements: '*[*]',
     extended_valid_elements: 'svg[*],dd[*],dt[*],dl[*],defs[*],pattern[*],desc[*],metadata[*],g[*],mask[*],path[*],line[*],marker[*],rect[*],circle[*]',
});
</script>

<form method="post" action="dump.php">
    <textarea name="content"></textarea>
</form>
```

Copy the configuration to https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/ and paste the following code in "<>" save and immediately press "<>" again.

```
<dl>
  <div>
    <dt>title</dt>
    <dd>desc</dd>
  </div>
</dl>
```

After that, this is what comes out:

```
<div>titledesc</div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl?retiredLocale=de#wrapping_name-value_groups_in_div_elements

I have no idea how to turn off this validation. The documentation does not help me any more. Does anyone have an idea?

I have also tried the following configuration without success.

```
        cleanup_on_startup: false,
        trim_span_elements: false,
        verify_html: false,
        cleanup: false,
        convert_urls: false,
        valid_elements: '*[*]',
        valid_children: '*[*]',
        invalid_elements: '',
        fix_table_elements: false,
        force_br_newlines: false,
        force_p_newlines: false,
        forced_root_block: '',
        fix_list_elements: false,
        extended_valid_elements:
          'svg[*],dd[*],dt[*],dl[*],defs[*],pattern[*],desc[*],metadata[*],g[*],mask[*],path[*],line[*],marker[*],rect[*],circle[*]',
```